# ERROR 404 Django project has a wrong current path

Tags: python, django

I was creating a basic website following this tutorial:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/skeleton_website

When I tried to redirect the home page to my django app called unihub this error prompted:

```
Using the URLconf defined in TFGsWeb.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
unihub/
^static\/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, catalog/, didn't match any of these.
```

My files look like this:

**/TFGsWeb/settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'unihub.apps.UnihubConfig',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'TFGsWeb.urls'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**/TFGsWeb/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

# Use include() to add paths from the unihub application 
from django.urls import include

# Add URL maps to redirect the base URL to our application
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('unihub/', include('unihub.urls')),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/unihub/', permanent=True)),
]

# Use static() to add url mapping to serve static files during development (only)
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**/TFGsWeb/unihub/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

]
```

I don't understand why this catalog/ appears when I see no reference to any app or path named catalog/ in the files I did modify.

I'd also like to upload this project to my github so should I just do this for the keys or sensible settings info?

```
with open('./secret_key.txt') as f:
    SECRET_KEY = f.read().strip()
```

Comment: Look at the URL you're trying in the browser. It probably ends with `/catalog`

Comment: yes, the problem is that automatically redirects to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/` when i visit `http://127.0.0.1:8000` when it should redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/unihub/ ` >I mean, the error has to appear, but the problem is that it redirects to catalog/ not unihub by default

Comment: Is this really a redirect from Django? Do you see the 301 or 302 response? Or is it a redirect from the frontend?

Comment: on the terminal the only thing I see is a 404 `Not Found: /catalog/
[25/Jan/2019 23:08:31] "GET /catalog/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2299` when I just searched for `http://127.0.0.1:8000` in the browser

Comment: Check your browser's network tab in the development tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

When I tried to reproduce the "error" in other browsers it didn't happen so my guess is that...

Was not the app itself but the web browser that stored `http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/`  as the link to go to if the web does not have a valid redirect.

Thanks everyone for the support, I changed the url patterns to the suggested ones.

Answer (score 1):

Your `unihub` application on the mentioned url (`/`) might be calling (some ajax) or redirecting some `catalog` app url (specifically `catalog/`).

Include in your urls the urls from catalog app and/or add such app to your installed apps.

On the other hand, you don't need a `RedirectView` to point `/` to your view just write:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('unihub/', include('unihub.urls')),
    path('', include('unihub.urls')),
]
```

Comment: the problem is that I have no catalog app in my web and I don't need one, yet the tutorial has. I searched for any reference to the catalog app in the code and haven't found any. I just need that the web stops redirecting me to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/` when I search `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, I'd like it to redirect me to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/unihub/`

Comment: It is not possible your code (or libs your're using) not redirecting/calling to `/catalog/` somehow, perhaps some template is using some url name or something as `{% url some_name %}`, where some name points to `/catalog/`.